# What is the importance of local connectedness and local path connectedness?

Tags: general-topology

> A space $X$ is said to be locally connected at $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ contained in $U$. If $X$ is locally connected at each of its points, it is said simply to be locally connected. Similarly, a space $X$ is said to be locally path connected at $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a path-connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ contained in $U$. If $X$ is locally path connected at each of its point, then it is said to be locally path connected. (Sect-25 , Munkres)

Thinking in terms of components, I understand that we can find a "squashable" open neighborhood $V$ in $U$ which can be squashed turned into a point by the quotient relations (*). But, I fail to understand why the above idea is important.

I have seen in many places before the ideas of connectedness and path connectedness being used but I fail to understand how the idea of their local versions are important. Could someone give more context to these definitions? Thanks.

*: For local path connectedness, we can find a $V$ which collapses to a point under the path connectedness quotient and similarly for local connectedness.

Comment: Local versions are needed for many lifting theorems, especially in the theory of covering spaces.